# Keras how to multiply with a changing variable in models

Tags: keras

I'm currently trying to create a mask for the logit layer in Keras.  This mask is not static though, and it's always changing when I'm calling model.predict.  Is there any way to implement this?

```
self.mask_change = np.zeros(104)

def build_model(self):
    input = Input(shape=(14,))
    layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)
    layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer)
    logit = Dense(104)(layer)
    masked_logit = Lambda(lambda x: x*self.mask_change)(logit)
    output = Activation('softmax')(masked_logit)
    model = Model(input, output)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
```

While this runs, if I change self.mask_change somewhere in the program then call model.predict(), it will always return the output of whatever self.mask_change was when the model was built.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the mask as an extra input to your model:

```
def build_model(self):
    input = Input(shape=(14,))
    mask = Input(shape=(104,))
    layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)
    layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer)
    logit = Dense(104)(layer)
    masked_logit = logit * mask
    output = Activation('softmax')(masked_logit)
    model = Model([input, mask], output)
```

When you call predict you can pass a different mask, `model.predict([input, mask_change])` every time. The mask is no longer fixed in the model this way.

Comment: while this works (I had to use Lambda for the logit*mask operation though), is there really no other another way?  For example, if my model has like 20 of these variables, passing all of them in as inputs would be quite painful...

Comment: You could again pass as a single input and then slice it, so if you two masks `Input(shape=(104*2,))` then slice `m1 = masks[:105]`.

Comment: I meant if they are different variables (size, type, etc).  in tensorflow it seems you could access variables outside of the graph with self.whatever_name (probably just need placeholder for them first), is this not possible for keras model building?

Comment: The `Input` layer wraps the placeholder, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: yep you are right, I was confusing it with something else.